# redux-sagas generator yield failing inside callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, generator, firebase-authentication, redux-saga

I'm trying to set up a redux registration and auth flow through firebase, using sagas middleware. However I'm getting:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (16:3)

  14 |  registerUser(action.creds).then(response => {
  15 |      if(response.payload.errorCode)
> 16 |          yield put({type: 'REGISTRATION_FAILED', message: {msg_type: 'error', msg_body: response.payload.errorMessage}})
     |          ^
  17 |      else
  18 |          yield put({type: 'REGISTRATION_SUCCESSFUL', user: response})
  19 |  });
```

a bit generic, but moving that line of code around it seems that yield specifically does not like being in a callback. However I don't see anywhere this is specifically disallowed. Is there a better way to be doing this? Here's the saga generator.

```
export function* registerUserSaga(action){
    console.log('registerUser called')
    console.log(action)

    registerUser(action.creds).then(response => {
        if(response.payload.errorCode)
            yield put({type: 'REGISTRATION_FAILED', message: {msg_type: 'error', msg_body: response.payload.errorMessage}})
        else
            yield put({type: 'REGISTRATION_SUCCESSFUL', user: response})
    });
}
```

and here is the firebase registration function:

```
export default FireBaseTools = {
    registerUser: (creds) => {
        return firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(creds.email, creds.password).then(user => {
          return user;
        }).catch(error => {
          return {
            errorCode: error.code,
            errorMessage: error.message
          }
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT: originally I thought this was cause by the if/else, but the callback seems to be the real culprit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use Promise from registerUser function;

something like that:

```
registerUser: creds => {
    return firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(creds.email, creds.password)
    .then(user => ({user}) )
    .catch(error => ({error}))
}

export function* registerUserSaga(action){

    const {error, user} = yield call(registerUser,action.creds);
    error 
    ? yield put({type: 'REGISTRATION_FAILED',
               message: {msg_type: 'error', msg_body: error.message}})

    : yield put({type: 'REGISTRATION_SUCCESSFUL', user});
}
```